# create guid and send with confirmation link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create guid using the code this

```
sGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

And passing it with the confirmation link using this:

```
const string body = "To confirm 'http://www.mysite.com/verify.aspx?sGuid'Verify your account";
```

But, I find that in my email inbox massage it looks like

```
http://www.mysite.com/verify.aspx?sGuid
```

The confirmation link shows no guid. I can't find what is wrong. I am using localhost .**Is there anyway to test the confirmation link at using localhost?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use concatenation to add your actual guid to link:

```
string body = "To confirm 'http://www.mysite.com/verify.aspx?sGuid=" + sGuid + "'Verify your account";
```

And than, in `verify.aspx.cs` you should be able to get it like:

```
string guidToTest = Request["sGuid"];
```

Also, please note that you can't use `const` modifier defining `body` as you will be unable to use concatenation.

But if you want to have it like a const property of your class, you may do something like this:

```
const string body = "To confirm 'http://www.mysite.com/verify.aspx?sGuid={0}'Verify your account";
```

And than, before sending an email:

```
mail.Body = string.Format(body, sGuid);
```

As mentioned by @house9 in comment below.

And there is no difference if you are working with localhost or not.

Comment: or String.Format ? - `string body = String.Format("To confirm 'http://www.mysite.com/verify.aspx?sGuid={0}' Verify your account", sGuid);`

Comment: above is working fine.how i can test the confirmation link using localhost?

Comment: @house9 thanks. I would choose some `.Replace` (just do not like format for some reason :) )

Comment: @user1927791 And what stops you from changing www.mysite.com to localhost? Or what ever name your local site has...